# ElasticSearch: query about a specific position in nested list

Tags: json, elasticsearch, querydsl

I have an ES index with documents like these:

```
[{"type": "alpha", "order": ['john', 'michael', 'tony']}]
[{"type": "alpha", "order": ['michael', 'john', 'tony']}]
[{"type": "beta", "order": ['michael', 'john', 'tony']}]
```

My query needs to return a record in which the "type" is "alpha" and where "john" is in the second position on the "order" list. I've been trying with nested queries, but don't seem to be able to combine that with top-level condition for "type". Any hints welcome.

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done with your current mapping.

You have to shape your data like this :

```
[{"type": "alpha", "order": {"1":"john", "2":"michael", "3":"tony"]}]
```

or like this :

```
[{"type": "alpha", "order": [{"rank":1,"name":"john"}, {"rank":2,"name":"michael"}, {"rank":3, "name":"tony"}]}]
```

The second solution requires nested "order" and nested query, which is less efficient, but if you got a lot of orders, that might be a better solution in order to prevent [mapping explosion](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html#mapping-limit-settings).

Comment: This is very helpful! I can modify it to include "rank" and then the following should work. But it is still not clear to me how to add "type" constraint to this:

    query = {
        "query": {
            "nested": {
                "path": “order",
                "query": {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [{
                            "match": {
                                “rank": 2
                            }}
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

Comment: Your query fixed :

    {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [{
            "nested": {
              "path": "order",
              "query": {
                "match": {
                  "order.rank": 2
                }
              }
            }
          }, {
            "match": {
              "type": "alpha"
            }
          }]
        }
      }
    }

Beware to the nested field "order.rank", you got to give the full path again.